# linked list with function

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a program which creates and display linked list.

Now i'm having trouble with my create_list() function, it doesn't create any list.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Sorry for bad english :/

CODE :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int main(){

     node *start;
     start = NULL;
     int a,n,on = 1;

     while(on == 1){
        printf(" \n choose: \n 1 --- create list \n 2 --- display list \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        switch(n){
            case 1:
                printf("-------------------------------------------- \n");
                printf(" Enter the elements. The last element is 0 \n");
                printf("-------------------------------------------- \n");

                Create_list();
                Display_list(start);
                break;

            case 2:
                 Display_list(start);
                break;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void Display_list(node *curr){
    if(curr){
        while (curr->next != NULL){
                  printf("%d \n",curr->data);
                   curr=curr->next;
        }
    } else {
        printf(" \n The list is not created ! \n");
    }
}

void Create_list(node *curr){

    int i;
    node *start = NULL;



    if (start == NULL){
        curr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        start=curr;

       while ( i != 0){
            scanf("%d",&i);
            if(i == 0){
                curr->next=NULL;
                curr=start;
            } else {
                curr->data=i;
                curr->next=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                curr=curr->next;
            }
        }

    } else {
          printf(" \n list already exists ! \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: your indentation is hurting my eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function Create_List(node *curr) needs some arguments. You are not passing any arguments from main(). Did your code compile?

The function Create_List(node *curr) needs some arguments. You are not passing any arguments from main(). Did your code compile?

What you should do is take a node in main which will store location of first node of the linked list.

```
void Insert(struct node **q, int num) //Num is the data to be added and **q is the pointer to the first node of the list.
{
struct node *temp, *r;
temp = *q;
if (*q == NULL) {
    temp = ((struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)));
    temp->data = num;
    temp->link = NULL;
    *q = temp;
}
else    {
    while (temp->link != NULL)
        temp = temp->link;

    r = ((struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)));
    r->data = num;
    r->link = NULL;
    temp->link = r;
}
}
```

Comment: Yes it did, bet when i enter 1,2,3,0. it shows me "The list is not created !".

Comment: "pass &start (as a node**) from main into Create_list and modify *start to set the list head." as cHao said.

Answer (score 0):

The `start` in `Create_list` is not related to the `start` in `main`.  Since both are local to their respective functions, one can't even see the other.  So setting `start` doesn't actually set `start`, if you will.  :P

You'll need to either bring `start` outside of the functions and make it global, or pass `&start` (as a `node**`) from `main` into `Create_list` and modify `*start` to set the list head.  (The latter is generally preferable, as globals are often trouble waiting to happen.)